# KVM disk-based VM on a luks-encrypted disk

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, kvm, qemu, luks

I have an Arch linux running windows 10 disk-based VMs. The disk is on a different volume group and is luks encrypted. I have a logical volume for each VM with ext4 file system. I manually edited the fstab with the correct UUIDs and I set the type to ext4. Before I installed windows on the VMs I rebooted to make sure the fstab was configured properly. After the installations, I'm getting this error for each partition right after I correctly type in the password for the disk:

```
[TIME] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/1bdc0382-d2a4-4581-b737-feec147dec40.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /disk0.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/1bdc0382-d2a4-4581-b737-feec147dec40.
```

After those errors I get:

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in type [...]
```

I'm not a linux expert so the answer might be simpler than it seems. Anyone has any suggestion?

**EDIT #1:**

*fstab* snippet:

```
# /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0
UUID=1bdc0382-d2a4-4581-b737-feec147dec40   /disk0  ext4    rw,relatime 0 2
```

**EDIT #2:**

*lsblk -f* snippet:

```
NAME                FSTYPE      FSVER            LABEL       UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                                                                
`-sda1              crypto_LUKS 2                            48bd9c70-c5cd-42c0-a58e-f0257be18d44
  `-disk            LVM2_member LVM2 001                     IVCIiW-5r2w-AzHY-hWyE-iJ7g-IqPB-lUdP9o
    |-volgroup0-lv_disk0
    |                                                                                                              
    `-volgroup0-lv_disk1
```

*blkid* snippet:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="48bd9c70-c5cd-42c0-a58e-f0257be18d44" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="fe7085b2-c19b-1f48-908c-c59dd96bcfc9"
/dev/mapper/disk: UUID="IVCIiW-5r2w-AzHY-hWyE-iJ7g-IqPB-lUdP9o" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0: PTUUID="3421c065-23d3-48a1-8274-951444ce8d5c" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

**EDIT #3:**

*fdisk -l* snippet:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/disk: 447.12 GiB, 480086138368 bytes, 937668239 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.

Disk /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3421C065-23D3-48A1-8274-951444CE8D5C

Device                                   Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0-part1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0-part2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0-part3    239616 418403031 418163416 199.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0-part4 418404352 419426303   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
```

Comment: Can you clarify your disk setup? I understand that you have several logical volumes, each volume is LUKS encrypted, and there is a filesystem on each LUKS device. Is that correct? To understand better what is happening, disable the offending lines in /etc/fstab by commenting them and boot again. Add /etc/fstab and the output of `lsblk -f` as well as `blkid` to your question. By the way, both logical volumes and LUKS devices have persistent names out of the box, which you could use in /etc/fstab instead of the UUIDs. Names are easier to manage for humans than UUIDs.

Comment: Ok will do that. To clarify: I have a separated HDD for the VMs. The disk has 1 partition which is luks encrypted. That partition has logical volumes for each VM. I have added one of the lvm mapping on the fstab to the question. Will do the rest in a minute.

Comment: @berndbausch I have added snippets of the relevant parts because adding everything would pollute the post. If you need anything else, or for me to just dump everything let me know.

Comment: I see that you LUKS-encrypted `sda1`, then used the LUKS device as a physical volume and created a logical volume on it. So far so good and correct. However, there doesn't seem to be a filesystem on that logical volume `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0`, which means that it can't be mounted. Where did you get the UUID `1bdc0382-d2a4-4581-b737-feec147dec40` from?

Comment: @berndbausch I don't remember... I thought it was running *fdisk -l* but now I can't find it. I have edited the answer with an error shown in *fdisk -l*. **EDIT**: the other lvm on that disk does not show that same error.

Comment: @berndbausch Could it be possible that the installation of windows or the fact that I'm pointing a VM to the LV somehow screwed the file system? because I'm sure I rebooted the computer right after creating the LVs and editing fstab and it worked fine. I'm also 100% sure I **mkfs.ext4** both the LVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a logical volume as a backing storage for virtual machines, the LV will be used "directly" as disk for the VM -- the `ext4` filesystem you created was overwritten by the Windows installation so you can no longer mount it, because instead of `ext4` your `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0` LV now contains a partition table with Windows partitions.

If you want to access data from your Windows VM you can use [libguestfs](https://libguestfs.org/).

To fix your boot problem, remove the `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_disk0` entry from your `fstab`.